# Local Storage with multiple contentEditable

Tags: javascript, html

I have currently figured out a way to store value of 6am plan in a content editable box in my local storage key

> item [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNN7P.png)

How do I make this happen for all the other hours like [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I05Z2.png)

[work plan for every hour of the day 6 am - 11pm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I05Z2.png)

[storing input in one key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNN7P.png)

using this code snippet below
javascript -

```
var content = document.getElementById('content'),
address = document.getElementById('address'),
saveButton = document.getElementById('save'),
loadButton = document.getElementById('load'),
clearButton = document.getElementById('clear'),
resetButton = document.getElementById('reset');

var localStore = {
saveLocalStorage: function() {
localStorage.setItem('item', content.innerHTML);
},
loadLocalStorage: function() {
var contentStored = localStorage.getItem('item');
if ( contentStored ) {
content.innerHTML = contentStored;
}
},
clearLocalStorage: function() {
localStorage.removeItem('item');
}
};

saveButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
localStore.saveLocalStorage();
}, false);
```

```
<r class="notion-table-row">
<td
style="color: inherit; fill: inherit; border: 1px solid gb(233, 233, 231); position: relative; vertical-align: top; min-width: 122px; max-width: 122px; min-height: 32px;">
<div class="notion-table-cell">
<div class="notion-table-cell-text"
spellcheck="true" placeholder=" "
data-content-editable-leaf="true"
style="max-width: 100%; width: 100%; white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: break-word; caret-colour: gb(55, 53, 47); padding: 7px 9px; background-colour: transparent; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px;"
content editable="false">11 PM</div>
</div>
</td>
<td
style="color: inherit; fill: inherit; border: 1px solid gb(233, 233, 231); position: relative; vertical-align: top; min-width: 200px; max-width: 200px; min-height: 32px;">
<div class="notion-table-cell">
<div class="notion-table-cell-text"
spellcheck="true" placeholder=" "
data-content-editable-leaf="true"
style="max-width: 100%; width: 100%; white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: break-word; caret-colour: gb (55, 53, 47); padding: 7px 9px; background - colour: transparent; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px;"
<section id="11pm_input" content editable="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store all of the data in an array. Keep in mind, `localStorage` stores only strings so anything not a string (ex. array, object, number, etc.), must be converted into a string when saved to `localStorage`:

```
localStorage.setItem("String", JSON.stringify([...Array]))
```

and when it is retrieved from `localStorge` it needs to be parsed into it's original type:

```
 const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("String"));
```

In the example below, the data is gathered from all `.cell` which comprise of the following HTML elements from the table head and body (in ex. 4 x time, 6 x data):

```
<time class='cell' datetime="23:00">11 PM</time>

<data class='cell' value="0ne Zer0">Zer0 0ne</data>
```

---

```
time.datetime = "23:00";
time.textContent = "11 PM";

data.value = "0ne Zer0";
data.textContent = "Zer0 0ne";

lStorage = [
             ["23:00", "11 PM"],
             ["0ne Zer0", "Zer0 0ne"],
             ["00:00", "12 AM"],
             ...[N, N]
           ];
```

The event handler `manageData(event)` delegated all click events triggered on the table head, body, and foot.

- **Variables:**

  - `key` is whatever the user typed in `.input`, the value will be assigned to data being saved to `localStorage`.
  - `data` is declared for data coming from and to `localStorage`.
  - `cells` is an array of all `time.cell` and `data.cell` tags within the table head and body.
  - `node` is determined by `event.target` property which always refers to the tag the user actually clicked. This reference will be delegated to react according to the `.matches()` method and a series of flow control statements (`if`, `if else`, and `else`).

The process for loading data from `localStorage` involves `loadData(key)` and iteration of the array of arrays saved in `localStorage` and the array of `.cells`:

```
       if (node.matches('.load')) {...
       ...
         data = loadData(key);

         cells.forEach((n, i) => {
           n.textContent = data[i][1];
           if (n.matches('time')) {
             n.datetime = data[i][0];
           } else {
             n.value = data[i][0];
           }
         });
```

The rest of the code is of simular fashion -- here's a brief description of what it can do:

- **Load** data from key in `localStorage` and popualte a `<table>` with it.
- **Save** data from a `<table>` to a key in `localStorage`.
- **Reset** data the user typed in the fields (if given a selector, it can reset it as well).
- **Clear** data by key and all data in `<table>` (including static data).
- All `.cell`s are editable (including headers). Double click any `.cell` within the table head or body to toggle it in/out of edit mode.

***Due to SO security policy, WebStorage API will not function, go to: [Plunker](https://run.plnkr.co/preview/ckz3pfkfe0007386nlancnzqk/)***
The link doesn't work for me when clicked but
I managed to use the url by copy & paste
to the address bar:
https://run.plnkr.co/preview/ckz3pfkfe0007386nlancnzqk/ 
If the links above don't work, you can copy & paste the code in the Snippet with a text editor and save the file with a `*.html` extension.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <style>
     :root {
      font: 1ch/1.5 'Segoe UI';
    }
    
    body {
      font-size: 2ch;
    }
    
    table {
      table-layout: fixed;
      width: 70vw;
      margin: 20px auto;
    }
    
    th {
      width: 50%;
      font-size: 2.25rem;
    }
    
    td {
      vertical-align: center;
    }
    
    .box {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column nowrap;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      min-height: 32px;
      padding: 8px 8px 5px;
    }
    
    .cell {
      display: block;
      max-width: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 25px;
      white-space: pre-wrap;
      word-break: break-word;
      font-size: 2rem;
      border: 2px solid #000;
      background: transparent;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .head {
      width: 97.5%;
      border-color: transparent;
    }
    
    .edit {
      border-color: blue;
    }
    
    button {
      display: block;
      font: inherit;
      font-size: 2rem;
      background: transparent;
      border-radius: 6px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    button:hover {
      border-color: blue;
      color: blue;
      background: #ddd;
    }
    
    .ctrl {
      position: relative;
      flex-flow: row nowrap;
      justify-content: space-between;
      min-width: 92%;
      height: 30px;
      margin-top: 40px;
    }
    
    .input {
      position: absolute;
      top: -40px;
      left: -0.5vw;
      width: 99%;
      height: 25px;
    }
    
    .noKey {
      color: tomato;
      font-weight: 900;
      border-color: tomato;
    }
    
    .noKey::before {
      content: 'Enter the key to data';
    }
    
    .done {
      color: blue;
      border-color: blue;
    }
    
    .done::before {
      content: 'Data is saved under key: "';
    }
    
    .done::after {
      content: '"';
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <section>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <data class="cell head" value="Hour">Hour</data>
            </th>
            <th>
              <data class="cell head" value="Employee">Employee</data>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <fieldset class="box">
                <time class="cell">8 PM</time>
              </fieldset>
            </td>
            <td>
              <fieldset class="box">
                <data class="cell edit" contenteditable></data>
              </fieldset>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <fieldset class="box">
                <time class="cell">9 PM</time>
              </fieldset>
            </td>
            <td>
              <fieldset class="box">
                <data class="cell edit" contenteditable></data>
              </fieldset>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <fieldset class="box">
                <time class="cell">10 PM</time>
              </fieldset>
            </td>
            <td>
              <fieldset class="box">
                <data class="cell edit" contenteditable></data>
              </fieldset>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <fieldset class="box">
                <time class="cell">11 PM</time>
              </fieldset>
            </td>
            <td>
              <fieldset class="box">
                <data class="cell edit" contenteditable></data>
              </fieldset>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
              <fieldset class="ctrl box">
                <data class="cell input edit" contenteditable></data>
                <button class="load" title="Load data">
                    Load</button>
                <button class="save" title="Save data">
                    Save</button>
                <button class="reset" title="Reset fields">
                    Reset</button>
                <button class="clear" title="Clear saved data and Reset fields">
                    Clear</button>
              </fieldset>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </section>
  </main>
  <script>
    const tab = document.querySelector('table');
    const hdr = tab.tHead;
    const mid = tab.tBodies[0];
    const ftr = tab.tFoot;

    const cls = ['noKey', 'done'];
    const inp = document.querySelector('.input');

    const formatTime = time => {
      const T = time.split(' ');
      return T[1] === 'PM' ? `${+T[0]+12}:00` : `${T[0]}:00`;
    };

    const lastFirst = name => name.split(' ').reverse().join(', ');

    const loadData = key => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));

    const saveData = (key, data) => localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));

    const resetData = selector => {
      let nodes = selector === undefined ? '.edit' : selector;
      [...document.querySelectorAll(nodes)].forEach(n => {
        n.textContent = '';
        if (n.matches('time')) {
          n.datetime = '';
        } else {
          n.value = '';
        }
      });
      inp.classList.remove(...cls);
    };

    const clearData = key => {
      resetData('.cell');
      inp.classList.remove(...cls);
      localStorage.removeItem(key);
    };

    const manageData = e => {
      let key = inp.textContent;
      let data;
      const cells = [...document.querySelectorAll('.cell')];
      const node = e.target;

      if (node.matches('.load')) {
        if (key.length < 1) {
          inp.classList.add('noKey');
        } else {
          data = loadData(key);
          cells.forEach((n, i) => {
            n.textContent = data[i][1];
            if (n.matches('time')) {
              n.datetime = data[i][0];
            } else {
              n.value = data[i][0];
            }
          });
        }
      } else if (node.matches('.save')) {
        if (key.length < 1) {
          inp.classList.add('noKey');
        } else {
          data = cells.flatMap(n => {
            if (n.matches('time')) {
              n.datetime = formatTime(n.textContent);
              return [
                [n.datetime, n.textContent]
              ];
            } else {
              n.value = lastFirst(n.textContent);
              return [
                [n.value, n.textContent]
              ];
            }
          });
          inp.classList.add('done');
          saveData(key, data);
        }
      } else if (node.matches('.reset')) {
        resetData();
      } else if (node.matches('.clear')) {
        if (key.length < 1) {
          inp.classList.add('noKey');
        } else {
          clearData(key);
        }
      } else if (node.matches('.input')) {
        node.textContent = '';
        node.classList.remove(...cls);
      } else {
        return;
      }
    };

    ftr.onclick = manageData;

    const toggleEdit = e => {
      const node = e.target;
      if (node.matches('.cell')) {
        node.classList.toggle('edit');
        node.toggleAttribute('contenteditable');
      }
    };

    hdr.ondblclick = toggleEdit;
    mid.ondblclick = toggleEdit;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello zer00ne! 
I need your help in sending this data to a json file for mongodb atlas sync
Link to my question and code snippet  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70985119/array-content-empty-after-taking-input-in-text-area
Problem Statement - Table values -> Make JSON structure -> Pull/Push to db Your app should read a JSON in the same structure, and populate values. And send a JSON in same structure to db. For loading and saving

Comment: Hello @AkshatB sorry, I'm a frontend developer, I have no knowledge of the backend. Post another question with Mongo and Atlas tags.