# Array content empty after taking input in text area

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

The inputs I am taking in the textarea are not reflecting in the console (Check code snippet)
:

Array(1)

content: ""

line: 0

**Problem Statement** - Table values -> Make JSON structure -> Pull/Push to db
Your app should read a JSON in the same structure, and populate values. And send a JSON in same structure to db.
For loading and saving

```js
        $(document).ready(function(){
    var textarea = $('textarea').val();
    var linebreak = textarea.split('\n');
    var length = linebreak.length;
    var data = [];
    console.log(length);
    for ( var i = 0 ; i<length ; i++){
          
        data.push({ 'line': i , 'content': linebreak[i] });
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="index.js" async></script>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Basic Web Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea class="form-control ph" id="notes_inputbox" rows="5" placeholder=""></textarea>
        <textarea class="form-control ph" id="notes_inputbox" rows="5" placeholder=""></textarea>
        <textarea class="form-control ph" id="notes_inputbox" rows="5" placeholder=""></textarea>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to listen for the input and then add values to your object.

Comment: @Esszed do I need to write <input type="textarea" 
something like that to listen

Comment: Your code currently executes on page load - none of your textareas _have_ any value in them, at this point. You need to bind your function to an event handler such as `input` or `change`, and then read the _current_ value inside your callback function.

Comment: @AKSHATBHATAWDEKAR follow this link  it will help you <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338592/how-can-i-bind-to-the-change-event-of-a-textarea-in-jquery>

Comment: @CBroe how bind the function in event handler can you help me out ?